# Sending Image with Exif info from Windows Phone to Java Server

Tags: image, send, windows-phone, exif, java-server

I'm new in programming in Windows Phone (and StackOverflow tbh). Currently, I'm working on a task that concerns with sending images stored in the Windows Phone's storage (with Exif info) to a Java server. So far I have successfully send the byte stream from the Windows Phone client and construct the image on the Java side, however, the Exif information is somehow lost. I believe it's just the way I send it on Windows Phone that's causing the problem. Very much appreciated for any help or guidance ! 
Here's my code on the Windows Phone client:

```
// Windows Phone Client code (MainPage.xaml.cs)
// This function is called when an image is selected from
// the task PhotoChooserTask ptask, which brings
// a popup that allows the user to choose an image
// from the phone's storage
void ptask_Completed(object sender, PhotoResult e)
{
       if (e.TaskResult == TaskResult.OK && e.ChosenPhoto != null)
       {
           //Take JPEG stream and decode into a WriteableBitmap object
           App.CapturedImage = PictureDecoder.DecodeJpeg(e.ChosenPhoto);

           // Attempt to send the image
           WriteableBitmap pic = new WriteableBitmap(App.CapturedImage);
           MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();

           pic.SaveJpeg(stream, App.CapturedImage.PixelHeight, App.CapturedImage.PixelWidth, 0, 100);
           stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
           client.Send(stream);

           // Close the socket connection explicitly
           client.Close();
       }
   }
```

Here's the code in the SocketClient.cs

```
       public string Send(MemoryStream data)
       {
       byte[] msData = data.ToArray();

       if (_socket != null)
       {
           // Create SocketAsyncEventArgs context object
           SocketAsyncEventArgs socketEventArg = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();

           // Set properties on context object
           socketEventArg.RemoteEndPoint = _socket.RemoteEndPoint;
           socketEventArg.UserToken = null;

           socketEventArg.Completed += new EventHandler<SocketAsyncEventArgs>(delegate(object s, SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
           {
               _clientDone.Set();
           });

           // Add the data to be sent into the buffer
           socketEventArg.SetBuffer(msData, 0, msData.Length);

           // Sets the state of the event to nonsignaled, causing threads to block
           _clientDone.Reset();

           // Make an asynchronous Send request over the socket
           _socket.SendAsync(socketEventArg);

       }
       else
       {
           response = "Socket is not initialized";
       }

       return response;
   }
```

On the Java Server,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ServerSocket serverSocket;
    Socket client;
    try {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(PORT_NUMBER);
        while (true) {
            client = serverSocket.accept();

            // Extract exif info
            InputStream inputStream = client.getInputStream();
            InputStream stream = new BufferedInputStream(inputStream);

            // Create file from the inputStream
            File file = new File("image.jpg");
            try {
                OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(file);
                byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
                    for (int n; (n = stream.read(buffer)) != -1;) {
                        os.write(buffer, 0, n);
                    }
                }
```

The output image is identical to the one sent from the windows phone, just without any Exif information whatsoever. Anyone could point out what I did wrong that causes the information to be lost? I'm guessing because I called the SaveJpeg function in the windows phone code, rewriting the image file, and losing all information there, but I don't know how else to convert the image to byte and stream it.

Much help is appreciated ! Thank you.

Comment: It might help to simplify your code into a smaller and simpler test case that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: @RichardPena So I have created a WriteableBitMap, convert it to MemoryStream, then to byte array. The Jave server supposedly receives the byte array and write it to a file. The image is there, but I've lost Exif information. That's my problem..

Comment: @RichardPena I might be doing something that's unnecessary in these steps. So please feel free to comment !

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer to my own problem. For those of you who might have a problem with this. I simply use:

```
Byte[] imageData = new byte[e.ChosenPhoto.Length];
e.ChosenPhoto.Position = 0;
e.ChosenPhoto.Read(imageData, 0, imageData.Length);
```

Then send the byte array in my send function:

```
socketEventArg.SetBuffer(imageData, 0, imageData.Length);
```